# Tag.php not being recognized

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to style my `/post_tag/tag/` pages. For some reason, my `tag.php` just is not being recognized. It keeps defaulting to my `index.php`. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've posted my test code below.

I've already tried various file names involving `tag-id` and `tag-slug`.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Tag pages
 *
 * Used to display archive-type pages for posts in a tag.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 */
get_header(); ?>
helo
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Would like to see the above page when I go to `site/post_tag/tag`, but instead I see my index.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use tags very often but just did a quick check on my local install and for me tag.php is accessible through

```
www.site.com/tag/tag-name
```

If I use the url you suggested I get index.php but it's actually a 404 page(I can see in the page title) I just don't have a 404.php created.

Comment: For me /tag/tag-name comes up as 404. I thought this might just be something different in the site structure that didn't matter. As a side question, what do you mean in the page title? As in how do you know it's 404.

Comment: If you go to your tags in the backend (wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag) and hover over a tag there is a "view" link. Where does that bring you?

Comment: To the link I posted. Similarly if I use the get_tag_link() i get the same thing.

Comment: Hate to suggest this but just want to check if you've Reset Permalinks, Tried it with a default them and tried it with plugins deactivated to see if any of those are causing the issue?

Comment: I'm a little new to wordpress and php. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Also I can say I had to register the taxonomy, which I didn't think would be necessary for posts.

Comment: These are the usual checklists thing in Wordpress to try when you are having an issue. To reset permalinks go to Settings->Permalinks and just re-save your settings(I'd usually use post name for this setting) and see if it works this usually caused issues with url in Custom Post Types but worth a try. Then try deactivating all plugins and see if it works. Next try changing your theme to a Wordpress default theme twentynineteen or something simliar.

Comment: Tags should be there by default as far as I know and you shouldn't have to register it. In that case maybe the permalinks reset might work.

Comment: Okay so I've been messing around. Tags automatically show up in different themes regardless of my plugins, so it must be something with my theme. Do you have any suggestions on what to do next?

Comment: First place I'd look is my functions.php anything custom that you've written just comment it out and test the site. One thing that comes to mind is that there could be a clash in something that you've named the same as something that Wordpress uses as a name in it's core code, maybe post_tag??? https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms But again the best way to check is to comment out chunks of code if it works try narrow it down to the specific function that's causing the issue.